# Allowing for user-provided executive string with child_process.spawn()

Tags: node.js, child-process

Using node.js child_process#spawn, it might looks something like this:

```
const child = cp.spawn('npm', ['install','-D','suman'], {});
```

or like this:

```
const child = cp.spawn('foo', ['bar','baz'], {});
```

the user of my lib will provide a command string, similar to an NPM script.

an NPM script might look like so in package.json

```
scripts : {
  'test': 'npm test'
}
```

in my lib, the user might provided anything, something like:

```
'watchProcess': {
  'a' :{
     script: 'foo bar baz',
     include: [],
     exclude: []
   },
 'b' :{
     script: 'node rolo cholo',
     include: [],
     exclude: []
   },

 'c' :{
     script: 'java biz bang',
     include: [],
     exclude: []
   }

}
```

do I need to do anything special to parse the `watchProcess.a.script`/`watchProcess.b.script`/`watchProcess.c.script` strings?
Or I simply just tokenize it by splitting by whitespace, and then just put into child_process.spawn?

Answer (score 1):

You can take your strings at the key script and tokenize them (as you said) there is nothing more you can do !

Maybe you want to sort out certain chracters out of the string but that's most of the time not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, given my brief testing with this, the following appears to be all that is needed:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const execString = 'npm install --save suman';

const execStringArray = String(execString).split(/\s+/);  <<< key part
const executable = execStringArray.shift();

const child = cp.spawn(executable, execStringArray, {});
```

ultimately in plain text that just looks like:

```
const child = cp.spawn('npm', ['install','--save-dev','suman'], {});
```